# Is it normal, that redux creates so many storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I see many lines in terminal, is it really need to create so many storage?

```
4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }
14:47:39.619    4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }
14:47:39.667    4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }
14:47:39.673    4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }
14:47:39.780    4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }
14:47:40.044    4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }
14:47:40.061    4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }
14:47:40.145    4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }
14:47:40.329    4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }
```

There are more hundreds such a line.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any code that would cause that.

Comment: No it's unusual. You're probably using that Next.js wrapper wrongly, but it's hard to tell where the error is without code.

Comment: If you use `getServerSideProps` the client will ask the server for page props every route change so that will increase the times that logs shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing SSR or SSG, yes.

Your server-side store has no access to your client side data - and it has to keep the data separated for all the clients. So it has to create a new store for every request.